# angular soap No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and php soap service

Tags: php, angularjs, soap, cors

I'm trying to use [angular-soap](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap) module to consume a remote soap service written in php. 
For the server I'm following this example: [php soap server](http://www.html.it/articoli/web-service-soap-e-php-5-2/)
On server side, I added:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

But, on browser I get the error (on /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1 has alias "prove.locali"):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.89.210/soapserver/server.php?wsdl. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://prove.locali' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

If I just output some json on server.php file the header makes its work and there are no error.

```
<?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
    echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
?>
```

I also tryied a lot of public soap service with the same error.

I'm not really interested in use this specific soap service. I just want to create a working example with angular-soap and a simple remote soap service.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something on client side, but the error is misleading.

Please take a look at the code below.

The client:

```
var base_url = "http://192.168.89.210/soapserver/server.php";
var action = "getWebUrl";
var params = {'name': 'google'};
return $soap.post(base_url, action, params);
```

You can see server.php script and wsdl files here: [soap example](http://www.html.it/articoli/web-service-soap-e-php-5-2/).
I just changed server.php adding:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a BOM char on your server.php at the beginning of the script ? In this case, that char is sent in the response body and the header is never sent (header cannot be sent if body started to be sent).

EDIT: Try to change the file encoding with Notepad++ for example

Comment: If I change server.php to just output some json and reach it using client code in question the error related to access controll allow origins disappear, and on chrome developer tools (network tab) I can see the expected output.  So it doesn't seem to be an error related to encoding.